# How to override WooCommerce 3+ search_products function without touching the core

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to override the WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT::search_products()
The function is in the class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php starting at line 1193.

I can remove/override the lines I want to but if update woocommerce my changes will disappear.
Is there any way to do this in functions.php without touching WC core?

I just want to remove the posts.post_content from the query to make the search faster.

```html
$product_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
   $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
    $type_join
    WHERE (
     posts.post_title LIKE %s
     OR posts.post_content LIKE %s
     OR (
      postmeta.meta_key = '_sku' AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s
     )
    )
    AND posts.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "')
    AND posts.post_status IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_statuses ) . "')
    $type_where
    ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC
    ",
    $like_term,
    $like_term,
    $like_term
   )
  );
```

Comment: "I just want to remove the posts.post_content from the query to make the search faster." So remove this line:  OR posts.post_content LIKE %s

Comment: What I would like to do is to speed up the search by removing the description from the query. When I use the cross sell search function it takes a very long time to return the results as there are thousands of products in the db. If i remove that line, the search is obviously faster. I think i will need to write my own search and add it as  custom field next to the cross sell search.

Comment: I don't have any solution to your problem for now…

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyway!